# Bluetooth range of Windows phone

Tags: lumia, bluetooth

What is the **bluetooth range**(*the most distance kept by two phones where bluetooth connection didnt failed*) for windows phone ? Is it varry by phone-by-phone ?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, most cell phones use [Bluetooth power class 2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth#Uses), which has a typical range of 10 m (signal attenuation due to walls and other obstructions notwithstanding).

However, [according to T-Mobile](https://support.t-mobile.com/docs/DOC-6901), the Lumia 925 has a class 1 Bluetooth radio, which has a typical range of 100 m. It's possible that this applies to other high-end devices as well. Or it could just be a typo.